# WCF IParameterInspector return response object

Tags: wcf

I'm have a WCF service which does input parameter validation by using the IParameterInspector hook, prior to calling the actual service method (WCF provider side). Everything is working well and I return the validation error by a FaultException exception. My question is whether it is possible to return an object with the validation errors instead of an exception? See the following snippet:

```
public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        var errors = new List<string>();

        // Validate each input parameter
        foreach (var entity in inputs)
        {
            // executing bunch of IValidator<T>'s
        }

        if (errors.Count != 0)
        {
            ////throw new FaultException<List<string>>(errors, "Input parameter validation error");
            return new Response<object>(null, errors);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This obviously doesn't work - My question is whether it is possible to return a reponse object to the comsumer, from the BeforeCall (WCF provider side)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is interesting why dont you add fault contract to your webservice and let it perform validation without intercepting anything. If something goes wrong it will throw real fault by contract. It would be normal.

For your fault you can create a custom fault with a `List<string>` inside and it can be easily handled by your clients to display errors.

Comment: One of the main purposes for implementing a parameter inspector is to validate parameters prior to sending the message to the service. Although it would be quite possible to perform validation inside the service’s method (and you probably should), the downside is that messages containing invalid parameters still have to make the trip from the client to the service. The service’s throughput is reduced because it has to deal with the deserialization of the message and the construction of the response. It would be better to avoid this overhead and just reject the message on the client side.

Comment: If you can validate parameters prior sending them to the service why make the call to the service in the first place with wrong parameters, add validation to client =). Usually parameter validation logic is only avaliable on the service in that case it doesnt provide anything great to put parameter validation into beforeCall inspector method.

Comment: Just so we're clear about the context - The BeforeCall event is on the WCF service provider side and not at the consumer side!

Comment: IParameterInspector can be implemented on both client and the serivce. In order to implement it on the client you need add it to the OperationDescription object found on the proxy. The following code demonstrates how this can be done: UpdateServiceClient proxy = new UpdateServiceClient();
Proxy.Endpoint.Contract.Operations[0].Behaviors.Add(new EmailAddressInspector());

Comment: OK Nina first of all we arent dealing with Client side BeforeCall handler like jaspernygaard says, second you can place before call handler on client, but how can you put server validation logic on client ?? =) Its called server validation logic for a reason. You cannot download server logic to client and use it there.

Comment: Not really a solution to the asked question, but we ended up using FaulException for all our validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I now, you can't return a custom object.Because return value's purpose is to allow BeforeCall methods to be correlated with AfterCall methods. The value returned from a BeforeCall will be passed into the corresponding AfterCall. Specifically, it’s in the correlationState parameter.

However, you can use `FaultException<T>` where T is your custom object with validation errors.

You need to define you custom class as follows:

```
public class DemoFault
{
[DataMember()]
public string ErrorText;
public DemoFault(string errorMessage)
{
ErrorText = errorMessage;
}
}

try
{
//blah blah blah
}
catch (FaultException<DemoFault> helloFault)
{
Console.WriteLine(hellofault.Detail.ErrorText);
}
```

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for... We return a Response<T> object from the service methods with errors. Throwing exceptions when validating input parameters and response objects when validating domain entities etc, will confuse the consumer. We might have to use FaultException through the whole service then...

Comment: Well, the return type needs to be a correlationState.

Comment: The FaultException<Response<object>> is what we're returning now from the consumer and it works. We would rather return an Response<object> object (which the service method also does)

Comment: @jaspernygaard: So you return `FaultException<Response<object>>` in BeforeCall method right ??? But how you manage this fault at client side. I have an iPhone which consume rest API. Can you provide some hint or code ??